# Sql DateDiff Question

Tags: sql-server

```
Select  distinct  DATEDIFF(ww, GETDATE(), siparis_test) AS Hafta
```

The first day of week is sunday in the above function. How can I change it so that monday is the first day?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the database system as a tag (sql server, postgresql, mysql,...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), e.g.

```
set datefirst 1
go
```